# Url binding in src iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

There is a method based on user id, getting the title and description, but video is not showing in IFRAME. Url binding in src IFRAME using ASP.NET C#

Aspx.cs code:

```
  public void getdata()
{

  bo.Para1 = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["userid"]) ? "no-img" : Request.QueryString["userid"];

 bl.videoDetais(bo, out  VDetails,out  Status);

 Lbl_title.Text = VDetails.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
 Txt_Description.Text = VDetails.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();  


  string url=null;

 url=VDetails.Rows[0]["YoutubeLink"].ToString();

 }
```

My Design IFRAME Code:

```
   <iframe width="480" height="360" src='<%# Eval("url") %>'
   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to have an accessible *url* property or field (not local) that's easier and more reliable. Also you should use `<%=` not `<%#`. Here is the full example:

(CodeFile/CodeBehind)

```
public string Url; // Maybe some default value?

public void getdata()
{
    // Operations
    Url = "http://whatever.com";
}
```

(Aspx Page)

```
<iframe width="480" height="360" src="<%= Url %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: src is passing correctly but video is not display.. why i have to use embed code or what

Comment: That's a new question. We don't know what your `VDetails.Rows` contains, so we can't help in this case.

Comment: VDetails.rows contain youtube url like  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44sd5f4d5 base on perticular user.

Comment: So you have to make it embed. For example: youtube.com/watch?v=OPf0YbXqDm0 to youtube.com/embed/watch?v=OPf0YbXqDm0